# Naturality in the Adjoint Property of Tensor Products

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, modules, tensor-products, adjoint-functors

In the **Lecture Notes in Algebraic Topology** by **Davis** and **Kirk**, one has the following result

> **Proposition 1.14** (Adjoint Property of Tensor Products) *There is an isomorphism of $R$-modules $$\operatorname{Hom}_R(A \otimes_R B, C) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}_R(A, \operatorname{Hom}_R(B,C))$$ natural in $A$, $B$, $C$ given by* $\phi \leftrightarrow (a \mapsto (b \mapsto \phi(a \otimes b) ) ).$

My problem is it now to understand what exactly **natural in $A$, $B$, $C$** means.

When one talks about naturality, then one probably means there is a natural isomorphism. At least this is what I assume.

Let us consider the naturality in $A$ and denote the category of $R$-modules by $R\operatorname{-MOD}$. Then we can define two functors $\mathcal{F}^A, \mathcal{G}^A: R\operatorname{-MOD} \to R\operatorname{-MOD}$ by 
$$\mathcal{F}^A(X) = \operatorname{Hom}_R(X \otimes_R B, C), \quad \mathcal{G}^A(X) = \operatorname{Hom}_R(X, \operatorname{Hom}_R(B,C)).$$

Now the natural isomorphism $\eta^A: \mathcal{F}^A \Rightarrow \mathcal{G}^A$ must satisfy that for every $R$-module $X$ we have an $R$-module isomorphism $\eta^A_X: \mathcal{F}^A(X) \longrightarrow \mathcal{G}^A(X)$. This is true by the universal property (one notes that $\mathcal{G}^A(X)$ can be interpreted as an bilinear map $X \times B \to C$).

The point where I am not sure about is if $\mathcal{F}^A$ and $\mathcal{G}^A$ are actually functors. For instance, given an $R$-module homomorphism $f: X \to Y$, how does the induced morphism $\mathcal{F}^A(f): \mathcal{F}^A(X) \to \mathcal{F}^A(Y)$ look like? My first try was it to take a $g \in \mathcal{F}^A(X) = \operatorname{Hom}_R(X \otimes_R B, C)$, $x \otimes b \mapsto g(x \otimes b)$ and set $\mathcal{F}^A(f)(g) (x \otimes b) = g(f(x) \otimes b)$. But this does not make sense since $f$ does not need to be surjective and the first component of $\mathcal{F}^A(f)$ has to be defined on the whole module $Y$.

Now I am totally stuck and have no idea how to continue. Could someone please unwind my messy thoughts? That would be great.

Comment: As an example, if we have $C \to D$, we get maps $f: Hom(A \otimes B, C) \to Hom(A \otimes B, D)$ and $g: Hom(X,Hom(B,C)) \to Hom(X, Hom(B,D))$. Let $\phi_C$ and $\phi_D$ be the adjunction isomorphisms. The goal here is to show that $g \circ \phi_C= \phi_D \circ f$. We then have to do this for the $A$ and $B$ slots as well. Note everything is a functor because they're all basically compositions of other functors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you're missing is that the functor you call $\mathcal{F}^A$ is *contravariant*. We can compute it by unfolding notation.

Given $f : X \to Y$...

The morphism $f \otimes B : X \otimes B \to Y \otimes B$ is determined from the fact that $\otimes$ is a bifunctor. If mixing arrows and objects bothers you, note that $f \otimes B$ means the same thing as $f \otimes 1_B$.

This is, as you've presumably realized, the morphism $x \otimes b \mapsto f(x) \otimes b$.

Now, $\hom(-, C)$ is contravariant. Given any $g : U \to V$, $\hom(g, C) : \hom(V, C) \to \hom(U, C)$ is the mapping $h \mapsto h \circ g$. Note the reversal in the direction of the arrow.

So, $\hom(f \otimes B, C) : \hom(Y \otimes B, C) \to \hom(X \otimes B, C)$ is the function that sends $h : Y \otimes B \to C$ to the function $h \circ (f \otimes B) : X \otimes B \to C$. $h \circ (f \otimes B)$ is the mapping $x \otimes b \mapsto h(f(x) \otimes b)$.

And it will be true that this gives a natural isomorphism between functors

$$ \mathcal{F}^A, \mathcal{G}^A : (R\operatorname{-MOD})^{\mathrm{op}}  \to R\operatorname{-MOD} $$

It is ultimately true that both sides of the equation define naturally isomorphic functors

$$ (R\operatorname{-MOD})^{\mathrm{op}} \times (R\operatorname{-MOD})^{\mathrm{op}} \times R\operatorname{-MOD} \to R\operatorname{-MOD} $$